# Capturar información de un input a un arreglo

Tags: java, array, netbeans, controller

buenas noches lo que pasa es que tengo un carro de compras cuando se seleciona el producto me trae el producto y su precio pero no me trae la cantidad del producto que solicita el cliente

este es el código de la vista

```
   <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="position: absolute;top:190%;">
                         <h:outputLabel value="IdProducto:" for="idProducto" />
                         <h:inputText disabled="true" id="idProducto" value="#{productoController.productos.idProducto}" title="IdProducto" required="true" requiredMessage="The IdProducto field is required."/>
                         <h:outputLabel value="Nombre:" for="nombre" />
                         <h:inputText disabled="true" id="nombre" value="#{productoController.productos.nombre}" title="Nombre" />
                         <h:outputLabel value="Precio:" for="precio" />
                         <h:inputText disabled="true" id="precio" value="#{productoController.productos.precio}" title="Precio" />
                         <h:outputLabel value="Cantidad:" for="cantidad" />
                         <input  id="cantidad" value="#{productoController.cantidad}" title="IdProducto" required="true" requiredMessage="The IdProducto field is required."/>
                                
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
                          <i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>                   
  </h:panelGrid>
```

y este es el del método que estoy utilizando

```
DetalleVenta detalleventa = new DetalleVenta();
   detalleventa.setCodDetalle(codDetalle=codDetalle+1);
   detalleventa.setCantidad(cantidad);
   detalleventa.setCodBarra(Productos.getIdProducto());
   detalleventa.setNombreproducto(Productos.getNombre());
   detalleventa.setPrecioVenta(Productos.getPrecio());
   detalleventa.setTotal(total=detalleventa.getCantidad()*Productos.getPrecio());
   totalcompra+=detalleventa.getTotal();
   subtotal= detalleventa.getTotal();
   codDetalle=detalleventa.getCodDetalle();
   nombreproducto=detalleventa.getNombreproducto();
   cantidad=detalleventa.getCantidad();
   codProducto=detalleventa.getCodBarra();
   precioVenta=detalleventa.getPrecioVenta();
    listDetalleVenta.add(detalleventa);
    System.out.println("===============================///////=======");
    System.out.println("DetalleFact "+detalleventa.getCodDetalle());
    System.out.println("codigo "+detalleventa.getCodBarra());
    System.out.println("Nombre "+detalleventa.getNombreproducto());
    System.out.print("cantidad "+detalleventa.getCantidad());
    System.out.print("precio uniddad "+detalleventa.getPrecioVenta());
    System.out.print("valor compra "+detalleventa.getTotal());
```

les agradezco si me pueden brindar cualquier orientación